# MySQL selecting all (*) while using concat?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So basically I want to select all of the columns in that table, while also concatting a specific column.

E.g. **(This code doesnt work obviously)**

```
select *
concat("$", Cost),
from Restaurant
Order by Cost desc;
```

So basically it will print all the values and add a $ infront of the (decimal) values of the Cost table.

I know how to just do that column itself and make it work, which would be

```
    SELECT CONCAT("$", Cost) AS Cost
    FROM Restaurant;
```

Which works but only prints out that column. How would I get it to print all the columns while still adding the $ sign to the cost column?

Comment: Actually AFAIK `SELECT *, CONCAT('$', Cost) ...` should be working just fine.  Don't put the `$` in double quotes, otherwise MySQL might think you are trying to refer to a column or other database object name.

Comment: The problem appears the be the missing comma after `*`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I still get the error "select" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLE, VALUES, WITH, '(' if I try what you both said

Comment: Sorry, try: `SELECT r.*, CONCAT('$', Cost) AS blah FROM Restaurant r` ... you might need to prefix the `*` with a table alias (or full table name).

Comment: I would not put the `$` in the query result. Just fetch the value, and use application code to format it as currency during presentation.

Comment: @BillKarwin I might say that your comment above is price _less_ LOL `:-)`

Comment: No problems here with double-quotes and no table alias ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e104c5/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like just misplacing comma in your select :

```
select 
    * , 
    concat("$", Cost)
from Restaurant
Order by Cost desc;
```